# Count changed lines in a file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-20.04

I have designed a script where you introduce the name of a file and change a given letter from lowercase to uppercase. For example I select to change "e" to "E" and I do not know how to count on how many lines this happend.

Here is my script

```
echo "Introduce el nombre del fichero para cambiar para la letra $1:"
read fichero1
sed "s/$1/\U$1/g" $fichero1 > resultados.txt.59773
echo "Número de líneas cambiadas en el fichero $fichero1: "
echo "Introduce el nombre del fichero para cambiar para la letra $2:"
read fichero2
sed "s/$2/\U$2/g" $fichero2 >> resultados.txt.59773
echo "Número de líneas cambiadas en el fichero $fichero2: ..."
echo "Introduce el nombre del fichero para cambiar para la letra $3:"
read fichero3
sed "s/$3/\U$3/g" $fichero3 >> resultados.txt.59773
echo "Número de líneas cambiadas en el fichero $fichero3: ..."
```

As you can see I want to count the lines where the sed command acts in the files

Thank you everyone

Comment: Please show your code. We can't tell you how it could be modified or enhanced to solve the problem without seeing the code.

Comment: It might be easiest to count the number of lines that contain a `e` first with `grep -c "e" file`, and then assume that this is the number of lines that will change with your second

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that I want it generally because the program works with any letter [a-z]

Comment: It might be easiest to count the number of lines that contain your letter first with `grep -c "your letter" file`, and then assume that this is the number of lines that will change with your second command. You can use variables with `grep` just like you can with `sed`, so this is not restricted to any specific letter.